# Interdependent header files and class/methods can't compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, header-files

I'm currently working on building a small ECS system, and in the process, I created an Application.h and Gameobject.h, where the Gameobject.h file requires both the declaration of the application class and some of its methods, and Application.h requires the gameobject class and some of its methods. I tried using a forward declaration of both the classes, but that doesn't help when it comes to getting class methods that are yet undefined, as the forward declaration doesn't define the class methods.

This is Gameobject.h:

```
    #pragma once

#include "Common.h"

class Gameobject
{
    friend class Application;

public:
    Gameobject(std::string name)
        :name(name) 
    {
        Application::Get()->AddGameobject(this);
    }

    std::string name;

    template<typename TComponent>
    void AddComponent()
    {
        DERIVES_FROM_COMPONENT;

        TComponent* component = new TComponent();
        component->SetGameobject(this);

        m_Components.push_back((Component*)&component);
    }   
    
    template<typename TComponent>
    void RemoveComponent()
    {
        for (const Component& component : m_Components)
        {
            if (typeid(component) == TComponent)
            {
                m_Components.erase(component);
                delete component; 
                
                return;
            }
        }
    }

private:

    void OnUpdate()
    {
        for (Component* component : m_Components)
        {
            component->OnUpdate();
        }
    }

    std::vector<Component*> m_Components;
};
```

And Appplication.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Common.h"

class Application
{
    friend class Gameobject;

public:

    static Application* Get()
    {
        //make a unique pointer later
        static Application* s_Instance = new Application();

        return s_Instance;
    }

    void Run()
    {
        std::cout << "Running";

        while (isRunning)
        {
            for (Gameobject* gameobject : m_Gameobjects)
            {
                gameobject->OnUpdate();
            }
        }
    }

    bool Close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool isRunning = true;

private:

    Application() {};

    ~Application() { delete Get(); }

    void AddGameobject(Gameobject* gameobject)
    {
        m_Gameobjects.push_back(gameobject);
    }

    void RemoveGameobject(Gameobject* gameobject)
    {
        const auto& it = std::find(m_Gameobjects.begin(), m_Gameobjects.end(), gameobject);
        m_Gameobjects.erase(it);
    }

    std::vector<Gameobject*> m_Gameobjects;
};
```

then Common.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Gameobject;

#include "ECS.h"
#include "Components.h"

#include "Application.h"
#include "Gameobject.h"
```

So the gameobject constructor requires the application.AddGameobject method and Application.Run() require gameobject.OnUpdate()

I'm still relatively new to C++, so is there something I'm missing that would make linking and compiling this easier or otherwise just solve the issue?

-thanks

Comment: Are you trying to learn C++ coming from a Java background? The shown code assumes that C++ works like Java, when it comes to class inter-dependencies. However, C++ is not Java, and requires dependencies like this to be handled quite differently.

Comment: No, I come from c#, so all this under the hood stuff is very new to me. How would I handle it in a c++ setting more correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pitfall from those coming from Java (and likely C#) backgrounds. C++ sparingly defines class methods in header files, and only ***if they don't require any other dependencies, other than the class itself*** -- perhaps something else might be `#included` that they can use, but that's going off on a tangent. Anyway, in your `GameObject.h` header file:

```
Gameobject(std::string name)
    :name(name) 
{
    Application::Get()->AddGameobject(this);
}
```

In order to compile this in C++, `Application` class to be ***fully defined***. Unless that class is fully defined, your C++ compiler has no idea what `AddGameObject` is all about. It's some mysterious method of whatever `Get()` returns, which is not defined anywhere, either. It's a big mystery to your C++ compiler, which is compiling this header file and has no other information about the `Application` class other than its name.

To do this `Application`'s header file can simply be `#include`d, of course. But then you will discover that `Application`'s methods also require `GameObject` to be fully defined as well, before ***they*** can get compiled. Somebody has to go first. Somebody has to be fully defined first. But you have two classes whose methods require the other class to be fully defined first.

This is why in C++ class methods are rarely fully defined, inline, in the header file. Here, you only need to ***declare*** the constructor in the header file:

```
class Gameobject
{
public:
    Gameobject(std::string name);
```

(it's also unclear that `Application` if needs to be a `friend` of this class in the first place). Then in the `Application.cpp` file, you `#include` both header files, and define the constructor:

```
GameObject::GameObject(std::string name)
    :name{name} // Might as well start using modern C++'s uniform initialization syntax 
    {
        Application::Get()->AddGameobject(this);
    }
```

Since both classes are now fully defined, by including their header files, this constructor can now compile, but only after fixing all other, similar, mutually-dependent methods. You'll need to remove all of them from the header files, and only declare them; then fully defining them in their appropriate `.cpp` files, after `#include`ing all required header files, for both classes.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was planning on implementing the classes in .cpp files at a later point, I didn't know it all had such a big effect on the code in terms of declaration and implementation dependencies. Thank you very much for your help